# git-svn: Keep .svn dir(s)

Tags: git, svn, metadata

I'd like to use Git SVN for project at my company where we use SVN. However build scripts there retrieve some SVN information from working copy (state of WC, current revision, ...) either via `svn` binary or SvnKit. So `.svn` *metadata* dirs must be present (or one in root for SVN 1.7). Can git-svn maintain these directories?

EDIT: I'm not in position to change SCM tool. The build scripts must keep working for rest of company that uses only SVN.

Comment: Why do this build scripts needs to know about the vcs?! O_o

Comment: Depending on which information you need, you may get it or not from git-svn. For instance, you can get current revision using `git svn info | awk '/^Revision:/ {print $2}'` But why just not to use Subversion for build scripts and Git for developers?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, `git-svn` won't create these directories for you.  Is there a chance to change how the build scripts work?  Perhaps they could stop checking the revision number, or you could put a git equivalent command in it's place?

Keep in mind that it could be a local tweak to the build process.  I did this for a year on a project. :-)

Comment: When we migrated from svn to git I have just changed the build scripts to detect what kind of repository is being used and use git-specific ways of fetching the info is they're on git. I think it's better in the long run, since it makes git more viable even for your collegues.

Answer (score 0):

The `.svn` directories could be versioned with Git like any other directory.

They have no special meaning for Git. So it shall be no problem.

Comment: Except, that it blows the repository into giant sizes :D

Comment: And commit made to subversion and then brought to git-svn won't have the directories.

Comment: Currently I do it like this. Eg. I've SVN repo inside Git repo. The problem is that 1) I can't sync commits between SVN and Git. When I do several local Git commits I then need to do one different commit to SVN. 2) .svn metadata changes on many occasions (svn status) and I can't exclude them (or I'd break SVN repo).